# Damaged Forks on Giant Tough Road 2

Tags: repair

I have recently crashed my Tough Road 2 and slightly damaged the forks at the point where the pannier rack is attached. The retaining bolt is slightly lifted and I am concerned that the forks are broken beyond repair. The local shop suggests that I need to replace them......a wait of 11 weeks. any suggestions to worth while repair or replacement would be appreciated. I am currently using 29*2.1 Schwalbe Big Sam tyres

Comment: You might want to change the name of the question to a question.

Comment: good point - well made. I am a novice at this Tinternet forum thingy, so bear with me :-)

Answer (score 3):

A quick google suggest this bike is fitted with composite forks. I would follow the shops advice and replace them. In composite forks damage can be more substantial than is immediately obvious and fork failure could produce a horrible crash.

If the wait is too long for an exact replacement then there are after market alternatives (such as as exotic carbon forks or planet-x/on-one forks). The key dimensions to match are the steerer size (probably tapered), axle to crown measurement (measure between the underside of the crown bearing race and the centre of the axle) and the wheel attachment mechanism (quick release, through axle etc).

Even if longer term you wanted the 'correct' fork an after market item would allow you to use the bike until the oem item can be obtained.

Note the forks mentioned are available in the UK market, if you are none UK then these might not be an option for you.

Comment: I am awaiting replacement forks - it seems their are none in the UK and there is a 12 week lead time  - I am a little impatient to use my new toy. An after market set would do it for me for now. Thanks for you words

Answer (score 0):

Depends how damaged the fork is.  Take it to another LBS for a second opinion.  Could be that your pannier rack took most of the impact and the threadded hole is damaged but the fork could be okay.

Note there's a fairly good chance your wheel/hub is okay.

A second/third opinion will help you decide if the first shop just wants to sell forks.

Also consider your own gut feeling - you were the one in the crash and you experienced the impact.

Comment: The upper locating lug for the pannier rack is where the damage is. With some carbon fibre repair tape/resin I have hope that the fork can be repaired till new forks are available. The wheel seems fine, the large tyre took the brunt of the whack and is split and has been replaced. I am very grateful that I was wearing a cycle helmet as I landed on my head on a tree stump, lol The helmet has been replaced. Accidents can be awfully expensive, eh.

Comment: That accident _without_ a helmet would have been a _whole lot_ more expensive! I remember [this Bell ad](http://p.vitalmx.com/photos/forums/2012/11/30/10_Bell_154524.jpg) from my youth. (sourced from a MX forum - don't know where he found it.)